# Is avoiding new on a object possible/desireble in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class

```
public class AClass
{
    private integer x,y,z;
    public AClass()
    {
        Initialize x,y,z;
    }
    public AClass RetB(integer x, AClass C)
    {
        AClass B;
        B = new AClass();
        B = dosomething(x, C);
        return B;
    }
}
```

If I want to use RetB(y, C) I could do something like this in the main-method:

```
AClass MyB;
MyB = new Aclass();
MyB = RetB(2, CC);
```

But this way the constructor is called twice, once for MyB, and once in RetB. Is this natural for C#, or is it possible/needed to avoid it?

Thanks

Comment: No, that's not at all natural - why create a new instance of `AClass` if you're then going to ignore it? Note that the initialization performed on the new instance will *not* affect the values of `x`, `y` and `z` in the current class. It's hard to see what you're actually trying to achieve here...

Comment: Please update the question with what it is that you're trying to achieve.  The intention of your code is very unclear...

Comment: Make `RetB` `static`. Then it's a factory method and it makes more sense.

Comment: There is a pattern, called object pooling, that is about reusing objects. You aren't doing it, and rarely it is used/I have used in .NET

Comment: From Tim, I get the suggestion to make 'RetB' static. From Jon I get the impression that I can omit the line  'MyB = new Aclass();'. Is this correct? Is one of the alternatives more preferable?

Comment: What I want is to make RetB behave like a constructor, but avoid using the constructor. Because the name of constuctor is unclear (it is the class name, but it does not describe what it does).

Answer (score 0):

Static methods that return new objects are a pattern quite common. For example they are used in the .NET library for the various `int.Parse` (and in general for parsing) (and for tons of other things). As you've said, they are used when using directly an overload of the constructor wouldn't transmit exactly what is happening.

```
public class AClass
{
    private int x, y, z;

    public static readonly AClass Empty = new AClass();

    // So that you can't do a new AClass() outside of this class
    private AClass()
    {
    }

    public static AClass RetB(int x, AClass c)
    {
        AClass b;
        b = new AClass();
        b.x = x;

        if (c != null)
        {
            b.y = c.y;
            b.z = c.z;
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
AClass myA = AClass.RetB(1, null);
AClass myB = AClass.RetB(0, myB);
```

note that, being the constructor `private`, it's **illegal** to

```
AClass myC = new AClass(); // doesn't compile
```